# get only selected value on Javascript's Form serialize

Tags: javascript, forms, serialization

This is how I serialize my form data,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#result").text($("form").serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<div>
  <input type="text" name="FirstId" value="01">
  <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="9">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="FirstId" value="02">
  <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="8">
  </div>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

What I want to do is I want to get value only with checked checkbox.
For example, I want to get like

> {FirstId: 01, SecondId: 9}

only when the first checkbox is checked.

If both checkbox are checked, I want to get

> {FirstId: 01, SecondId: 9} , {FirstId: 02, SecondId: 8}

**Note:**
I just want to use `.serialize()` method,  not `.serializeJSON()`.

Comment: Please put your code within the question itself (you can use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input values in a form are only used if they have a `name` attribute. To do what you want to do, I propose to remove or set the name of the previous input depending on the checkbox value.

But the way you want your return value (in JSON) is impossible with only the `serialize()` function as it serializes the form in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` way.

So here are two solutions.

This one with `serialize()` that doesn't return exactly what you want

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#result").text($("form").serialize());
      });
      
      $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $(this).prev().attr("name", "FirstId");
        } else {
          $(this).prev().removeAttr('name');
        }
      });
      
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="">
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="01">
      <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="9">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="02">
      <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="8">
      </div>
    </form>

    <button>Serialize form values</button>

    <div id="result"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This one without `serialize()` that returns exactly what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function() {
    let result = [];

    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        let obj = {};
        obj[$(this).prev().attr("name")] = $(this).prev().val();
        obj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        result.push (obj);
    });

    $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<div>
  <input type="text" name="FirstId" value="01">
  <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="9">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="FirstId" value="02">
  <input type="checkbox" name="SecondId" value="8">
  </div>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @StevenSann I've adapted my answer